# How to publish and receive data from Android Studio and have it on Google Cloud IoT Core?

Tags: android-things, google-cloud-iot

I'm a student doing an Android Things project, which is about connecting Rasperi pi with an Accelerometer sensor to get acceleration data, I finished the coding part in Android Studio and the sensor is working fine, then I tried to connect my project to the cloud by following this tutorial: http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/tut-google-cloud-iot-core-mqtt-on-android/

I think I have to publish the accelerometer data to the cloud by calling this method below in MainActivity class, I did that but still have an error, see the **update** I did at end of this question please.

```
@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Accel X " + event.values[0]);
        Log.d(TAG, "Accel Y " + event.values[1]);
        Log.d(TAG, "Accel Z " + event.values[2]);
    }
```

Also, do I have to do something in the cloud platform to receive the data?, I already set up the communication with my Google IoT Core details as shown in the below code:

```
 communicator = new IotCoreCommunicator.Builder()
                .withContext(this)
                .withCloudRegion("us-central1") 
                .withProjectId("my-first-project-198704")  
                .withRegistryId("vibration") 
                .withDeviceId("my-device") 
                .withPrivateKeyRawFileId(R.raw.rsa_private)
                .build();
```

This is what I'm seeing in the cloud: [image]

And this is the acceleration data I have in Android Studio:
[image]

My project consists of two modules but here I will attach only the second module because the question is limited to 3000 characters only and the second module is what I need to edit I think.

**sample** module:

AccelerometerActivity class:

```
package com.cacaosd.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.cacaosd.adxl345.ADXL345SensorDriver;
import com.cacaosd.sample.BoardDefaults;

import java.io.IOException;

public class AccelerometerActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = AccelerometerActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ADXL345SensorDriver mSensorDriver;
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerDynamicSensorCallback(new SensorManager.DynamicSensorCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDynamicSensorConnected(Sensor sensor) {
                if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                    mSensorManager.registerListener(AccelerometerActivity.this,
                            sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
                }
            }


        });

        try {
            mSensorDriver = new ADXL345SensorDriver(BoardDefaults.getI2CPort());
            mSensorDriver.registerAccelerometerSensor();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error configuring sensor", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "Closing sensor");
        if (mSensorDriver != null) {
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
            try {
                mSensorDriver.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error closing sensor", e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mSensorDriver = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Accel X " + event.values[0]);
        Log.d(TAG, "Accel Y " + event.values[1]);
        Log.d(TAG, "Accel Z " + event.values[2]);
    }



    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        Log.i(TAG, "sensor accuracy changed: " + accuracy);

    }
}
```

BoardDefaults class:

```
    package com.cacaosd.sample;

import android.os.Build;

import com.google.android.things.pio.PeripheralManagerService;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by cagdas on 20.12.2016.
 */

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public class BoardDefaults {
    private static final String DEVICE_EDISON_ARDUINO = "edison_arduino";
    private static final String DEVICE_EDISON = "edison";
    private static final String DEVICE_RPI3 = "rpi3";
    private static final String DEVICE_NXP = "imx6ul";
    private static String sBoardVariant = "";

    /**
     * Return the preferred I2C port for each board.
     */
    public static String getI2CPort() {
        switch (getBoardVariant()) {
            case DEVICE_EDISON_ARDUINO:
                return "I2C6";
            case DEVICE_EDISON:
                return "I2C1";
            case DEVICE_RPI3:
                return "I2C1";
            case DEVICE_NXP:
                return "I2C2";
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown Build.DEVICE " + Build.DEVICE);
        }
    }

    private static String getBoardVariant() {
        if (!sBoardVariant.isEmpty()) {
            return sBoardVariant;
        }
        sBoardVariant = Build.DEVICE;
        // For the edison check the pin prefix
        // to always return Edison Breakout pin name when applicable.
        if (sBoardVariant.equals(DEVICE_EDISON)) {
            PeripheralManagerService pioService = new PeripheralManagerService();
            List<String> gpioList = pioService.getGpioList();
            if (gpioList.size() != 0) {
                String pin = gpioList.get(0);
                if (pin.startsWith("IO")) {
                    sBoardVariant = DEVICE_EDISON_ARDUINO;
                }
            }
        }
        return sBoardVariant;
    }
}
```

IotCoreCommunicator class:

```
    package com.cacaosd.sample1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

public class IotCoreCommunicator {

    private static final String SERVER_URI = "ssl://mqtt.googleapis.com:8883";

    public static class Builder {

        private Context context;
        private String projectId;
        private String cloudRegion;
        private String registryId;
        private String deviceId;
        private int privateKeyRawFileId;

        public Builder withContext(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withProjectId(String projectId) {
            this.projectId = projectId;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withCloudRegion(String cloudRegion) {
            this.cloudRegion = cloudRegion;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withRegistryId(String registryId) {
            this.registryId = registryId;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withDeviceId(String deviceId) {
            this.deviceId = deviceId;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withPrivateKeyRawFileId(int privateKeyRawFileId) {
            this.privateKeyRawFileId = privateKeyRawFileId;
            return this;
        }

        public IotCoreCommunicator build() {
            if (context == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("context must not be null");
            }

            if (projectId == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("projectId must not be null");
            }
            if (cloudRegion == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("cloudRegion must not be null");
            }
            if (registryId == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("registryId must not be null");
            }
            if (deviceId == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("deviceId must not be null");
            }
            String clientId = "projects/" + projectId + "/locations/" + cloudRegion + "/registries/" + registryId + "/devices/" + deviceId;

            if (privateKeyRawFileId == 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("privateKeyRawFileId must not be 0");
            }
            MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(context, SERVER_URI, clientId);
            IotCorePasswordGenerator passwordGenerator = new IotCorePasswordGenerator(projectId, context.getResources(), privateKeyRawFileId);
            return new IotCoreCommunicator(client, deviceId, passwordGenerator);
        }

    }

    private final MqttAndroidClient client;
    private final String deviceId;
    private final IotCorePasswordGenerator passwordGenerator;

    IotCoreCommunicator(MqttAndroidClient client, String deviceId, IotCorePasswordGenerator passwordGenerator) {
        this.client = client;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.passwordGenerator = passwordGenerator;
    }

    public void connect() {
        monitorConnection();
        clientConnect();
        subscribeToConfigChanges();
    }

    private void monitorConnection() {
        client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
                Log.e("TUT", "connection lost", cause);
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
                Log.d("TUT", "message arrived " + topic + " MSG " + message);
                // You need to do something with messages when they arrive
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
                Log.d("TUT", "delivery complete " + token);
            }
        });
    }

    private void clientConnect() {
        try {
            MqttConnectOptions connectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
            // Note that the the Google Cloud IoT Core only supports MQTT 3.1.1, and Paho requires that we explicitly set this.
            // If you don't, the server will immediately close its connection to your device.
            connectOptions.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1);

            // With Google Cloud IoT Core, the username field is ignored, however it must be set for the
            // Paho client library to send the password field. The password field is used to transmit a JWT to authorize the device.
            connectOptions.setUserName("unused-but-necessary");
            connectOptions.setPassword(passwordGenerator.createJwtRsaPassword());

            IMqttToken iMqttToken = client.connect(connectOptions);
            iMqttToken.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    Log.d("TUT", "success, connected");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Log.e("TUT", "failure, not connected", exception);
                }
            });
            iMqttToken.waitForCompletion(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
            Log.d("TUT", "IoT Core connection established.");
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Configuration is managed and sent from the IoT Core Platform
     */
    private void subscribeToConfigChanges() {
        try {
            client.subscribe("/devices/" + deviceId + "/config", 1);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public void publishMessage(String subtopic, String message) {
        String topic = "/devices/" + deviceId + "/" + subtopic;
        String payload = "{msg:\"" + message + "\"}";
        MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage(payload.getBytes());
        mqttMessage.setQos(1);
        try {
            client.publish(topic, mqttMessage);
            Log.d("TUT", "IoT Core message published. To topic: " + topic);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        try {
            Log.d("TUT", "IoT Core connection disconnected.");
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

IotCorePasswordGenerator class:

```
    package com.cacaosd.sample1;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Base64;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;

import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

class IotCorePasswordGenerator {

    private final String projectId;
    private final Resources resources;
    private final int privateKeyRawFileId;

    IotCorePasswordGenerator(String projectId, Resources resources, int privateKeyRawFileId) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.resources = resources;
        this.privateKeyRawFileId = privateKeyRawFileId;
    }

    char[] createJwtRsaPassword() {
        try {
            byte[] privateKeyBytes = decodePrivateKey(resources, privateKeyRawFileId);
            return createJwtRsaPassword(projectId, privateKeyBytes).toCharArray();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Algorithm not supported. (developer error)", e);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid Key spec. (developer error)", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot read private key file.", e);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] decodePrivateKey(Resources resources, int privateKeyRawFileId) throws IOException {
        try(InputStream inStream = resources.openRawResource(privateKeyRawFileId)) {
            return Base64.decode(inputToString(inStream), Base64.DEFAULT);
        }
    }

    private static String inputToString(InputStream is) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }

    private static String createJwtRsaPassword(String projectId, byte[] privateKeyBytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        return createPassword(projectId, privateKeyBytes, "RSA", SignatureAlgorithm.RS256);
    }

    private static String createPassword(String projectId, byte[] privateKeyBytes, String algorithmName, SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        // Create a JWT to authenticate this device. The device will be disconnected after the token
        // expires, and will have to reconnect with a new token. The audience field should always be set
        // to the GCP project id.
        JwtBuilder jwtBuilder =
                Jwts.builder()
                        .setIssuedAt(Date.from(now))
                        .setExpiration(Date.from(now.plus(Duration.ofMinutes(20))))
                        .setAudience(projectId);

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithmName);

        return jwtBuilder.signWith(signatureAlgorithm, kf.generatePrivate(spec)).compact();
    }

}


MainActivity class:

    package com.cacaosd.sample1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Handler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;


import com.cacaosd.sample.AccelerometerActivity;
import com.cacaosd.sample.R;
import com.cacaosd.sample1.IotCoreCommunicator;


import com.google.android.things.pio.Gpio;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AccelerometerActivity mAccelerometerActivity = new AccelerometerActivity();

    private IotCoreCommunicator communicator;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup the communication with your Google IoT Core details
        communicator = new IotCoreCommunicator.Builder()
                .withContext(this)
                .withCloudRegion("us-central1") // ex: europe-west1
                .withProjectId("my-first-project-198704")   // ex: supercoolproject23236
                .withRegistryId("vibration") // ex: my-devices
                .withDeviceId("my-device") // ex: my-test-raspberry-pi
                .withPrivateKeyRawFileId(R.raw.rsa_private)
                .build();

        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("MyBackgroundThread");
        thread.start();
        handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
        handler.post(connectOffTheMainThread); // Use whatever threading mechanism you want
    }

    private final Runnable connectOffTheMainThread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            communicator.connect();

            handler.post(sendMqttMessage);
        }
    };



    private final Runnable sendMqttMessage = new Runnable() {
        private int i;

        /**
         * We post 100 messages as an example, 1 a second
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (i == 100) {
                return;
            }

            SensorEvent event = null;

            // events is the default topic for MQTT communication
            String subtopic = "events";
            // Your message you want to send
            String message = "Hello World " + i++;
            communicator.publishMessage(subtopic, message);



            handler.postDelayed(this, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        communicator.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

MainActivity class:

```
package com.cacaosd.sample1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Handler;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.util.Log;


import com.cacaosd.sample.AccelerometerActivity;
import com.cacaosd.sample.R;
import com.cacaosd.sample1.IotCoreCommunicator;


import com.google.android.things.pio.Gpio;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AccelerometerActivity mAccelerometerActivity = new AccelerometerActivity();

    private IotCoreCommunicator communicator;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup the communication with your Google IoT Core details
        communicator = new IotCoreCommunicator.Builder()
                .withContext(this)
                .withCloudRegion("us-central1") // ex: europe-west1
                .withProjectId("my-first-project-198704")   // ex: supercoolproject23236
                .withRegistryId("vibration") // ex: my-devices
                .withDeviceId("my-device") // ex: my-test-raspberry-pi
                .withPrivateKeyRawFileId(R.raw.rsa_private)
                .build();

        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("MyBackgroundThread");
        thread.start();
        handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper());
        handler.post(connectOffTheMainThread); // Use whatever threading mechanism you want
    }

    private final Runnable connectOffTheMainThread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            communicator.connect();

            handler.post(sendMqttMessage);
        }
    };



    private final Runnable sendMqttMessage = new Runnable() {
        private int i;

        /**
         * We post 100 messages as an example, 1 a second
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (i == 100) {
                return;
            }

            SensorEvent event = null;

            // events is the default topic for MQTT communication
            String subtopic = "events";
            // Your message you want to send
            String message = "Hello World " + i++;
            communicator.publishMessage(subtopic, message);



            handler.postDelayed(this, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        communicator.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I added a third input (int acceleration) on publishMessage() method inside IotCoreCommunicator class like below:

```
 public void publishMessage(String subtopic, String message, int acceleration) {
        String topic = "/devices/" + deviceId + "/" + subtopic;
        String payload = "{msg:\"" + message + "\"}";
        MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage(payload.getBytes());
        mqttMessage.setQos(1);
        try {
            client.publish(topic, mqttMessage);
            Log.d("TUT", "IoT Core message published. To topic: " + topic);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

Then I call it on run() method inside the MainActivity class like below:

```
 public void run() {
            if (i == 100) {
                return;
            }

            SensorEvent event = null;

            // events is the default topic for MQTT communication
            String subtopic = "events";
            // Your message you want to send
            String message = "Hello World " + i++;
            int acceleration = mAccelerometerActivity.onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event.values);
            communicator.publishMessage(subtopic, message, acceleration);



            handler.postDelayed(this, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
        }
    };
```

But I still have this error in the below screenshot:
(';' or ) expected)

[image]

Also the third input I added is shown like never been used as you see in the screenshot below, is this has any effect?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried converting the sensor data to a string and then sending it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mr. Nick Felker, please see the update on my question, I changed something but still have an error.

Comment: Based on the last two screenshots:

In Java, you do not specify the types. You don't put `SensorEvent event.value`, just `event.value`.

In the second screenshot, it's fine not to use all parameters of a method. (It'll compile, although it's not great code style)

Comment: You are getting a warning related to unused parameter because you are declaring it, but you are not using it in your specified method. By the way, it seems your problem is not related to google iot... apparently, it is related to android programming, right?

Comment: Hi Mr. Nick Felker, thank you for your reply, I did like you said and this error is shown: "onSensorChanged
(android.hardware.SensorEvent)
in AccelerometerActivity cannot be applied
to
(float[])"

Comment: Hi Mr. Dalton, thank you for your reply, previously I tried to publish String message only without the acceleration data, and the program worked without showing errors but I didn't get that String message inside the cloud, or may be I don't know where to finde it inside the cloud. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: Mr. Nick and Mr. Dalton, I post a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50142387/how-to-send-configuration-data-and-receive-the-device-state-using-google-cloud-i , I hope you see it.